# adb wakeup not wakes up galaxy s8

Tags: adb, standby, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I'm looking for adb command to wake up my galaxy s8.

When I had galaxy s7 I used successfully this command:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP
```

but in s8 this command just wake it up for a moment and then the screen is black again.

Can you help me find a way to wake up my phone and leave it awake?

Comment: I didn't find a solution but just disable the screen lock

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

`adb shell "dumpsys power | grep "Display Power: state=ON" | xargs -0 test -z" && adb shell input key event 26`

> This will first check to see if the screen is on. If it isn't, it will
>   emulate the power key, which will turn on the device's screen.

Credits: [Vimalraj Selvam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25507845/7551330)

Comment: I get an error: **'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command** maybe you can write it just in Linux? because I'm using Windows.

Comment: You can put the whole command in quotes